# Why does this jquery selector not recognize these images

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have an xml function I am using to load data and append to a div.
The css and jQuery for `div.thumb img` is not selecting the images.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loadfail() {  alert("Error: Failed to read file!");  }    

    //Load xml data
    function parse(document) {
        $("#thumbs").append('<div class="thumb">');

        $(document).find("entry").each(function () {
            var image = $(this).find('image').text();          

            $("#thumbs").append('<img src="Styles/images/' + image + '" width="64" height="64" />');           

        });

        $("#thumbs").append('</div>');

        $('div.thumb img').click(function () {
            $('#expandedimage').slideToggle(1000);
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'appdata/data.xml',    // name of file with our data  
        dataType: 'xml',       // type of file we will be reading  
        success: parse,        // name of function to call when done reading file 
        error: loadfail        // name of function to call when failed to read 
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
div.thumb { float:left ; padding: 1px; }
div.thumb img { border: 2px solid white; }
```

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="expandedimage">
        Toggled Image
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="thumbholder">                
        <div id="thumbs">
            <!-- image(s) here! -->
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>        
</div>
```

The code works when placing one div per image, instead of putting all images in one div:

```
$("#thumbs").append('<div class="thumb"><img src="Styles/images/' + image + '" width="64" height="64" /></div>');
```

However, the second `<br />` does not appear the images.

My question is then, why when I have one div and images in that div, `div.thumb img` does not work.

Comment: This piece doesn't make sense: `$("#thumbs").append('</div>');` you can't append just a closing tag or just an opening tag, all elements are appended as whole elements with both an opening and a closing tag or as self-closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the append function. You should append valid xml/html. TRy something along the line of.

```
function parse(document) {

 var containerDiv = $("#thumbs").append('<div class="thumb" />');

  $(document).find("entry").each(function () {
    var image = $(this).find('image').text();          

    containerDiv.append('<img src="Styles/images/' + image + '" width="64" height="64" />');           

  });


containerDiv.find('img').click(function () {

    $('#expandedimage').slideToggle(1000);
});
}
```

the append function does not append a text string but an element so you are appending the images as a sibling to div.thumb not as a child

Comment: Thanks Rune FS that worked. well has to change containerDiv.Find to containerDiv.find, changed css to `#thumbs .thumb { float:left ; padding: 1px; }
#thumbs img { border: 2px solid white; }` seems to look as expected.